# Monitor not displaying windows 7 correctly

Tags: windows-7, display, external-display

I have just got a 15" Digimate TFT LCD monitor. I'm running Windows 7.

Now the icons are too big, as are the windows in both browsers and word processing software - and everything has a bit to the left cut off, so for instance I can no longer see the back button in Chrome.

I've tried looking at the resolution and adjusting the monitor settings, but no luck. I've also tried updating drivers, but can't find any compatible ones.

Comment: Probably the graphic card issue might be the one you have to consider.

Comment: See if the DPI option helps (just type "dpi" at the start menu and select the "make text larger/smaller" option).

Comment: I'm guessing that's a fairly old monitor (I just looked at the Digimate website, and they don't seem to make anything smaller than 19" these days), but even so it should have an auto-adjust (sometimes it's a dedicated button, sometimes you have to hunt through the menu).  The bit about the left side being cut off sounds like a classic case for auto-adjust.  If that doesn't help, try a different VGA cable, especially if you can find a fat one (different manufacturers leave out different pins, and sometimes they don't agree - so a cable with ALL pins connected is best.)